# I can't foward a just recieved Email to a neighbor

Tags: windows

Using Windows 10 I cannot locate the icon that will foward a just received Email to another person. Never had this difficulty with windows 7 or other earlier software. Please advise.

Comment: You haven’t told us which email client you are even using